# How to enable ssh connection on azure

Tags: node.js, azure, ssh, dockerfile, port

I have trouble enabling the ssh connection for my azure web app (node js express server).
I have added this code to my Dockerfile.

```
RUN apt-get update \ 
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
  && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd

EXPOSE 2222 80
```

when entering ssh in azure, I get this message:

```
SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.16.207.2:2222
```

what else do I need to do, to make it work?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you cannot connect to the container even you enable the SSH following the steps is that you miss one step to complete the configuration. The step is that you also need to change the port the SSH listen to into port 2222 in the `sshd_config` file. What you have done just expose port 2222, but do not make the SSH listen to it.

The simplest way is copying the `sshd_config` [here](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/node/blob/master/10.14/sshd_config) and then add lines like this:

```
ENV SSH_PORT 2222
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this?

```
# ssh
ENV SSH_PASSWD "root:Docker!"
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
    && echo "$SSH_PASSWD" | chpasswd 

COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/
    
EXPOSE 8000 2222
```